# AfterShapeSizeChange application event not firing in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I've got a simple test .pptm file to try to debug the failure of the AfterShapeSizeChange event in PowerPoint 2013 (15.0.4659.1001) on Windows 7 x64.

In a standard module:

```
Public EH As New ClassEH

' Run to initialise PowerPoint application events
Sub InitApp()
  Set EH.App = PowerPoint.Application
End Sub
```

In a class module with name ClassEH:

```
Public WithEvents App As PowerPoint.Application

Private Sub App_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
  Debug.Print "App_WindowSelectionChange"
End Sub

Private Sub App_AfterShapeSizeChange(ByVal shp As Shape)
  Debug.Print "App_AfterShapeSizeChange"
End Sub
```

After running InitApp, the WindowSelectionChange event is firing as expected with a selection change but the AfterShapeSizeChange event is not firing after changing the size of a shape on the slide.

This event was added in PowerPoint 2013 as per this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227375(v=office.15).aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The shape size change fires OK here Jamie. I have 2013 Pro (msi version)

Comment: It's been a long time since I posted this question but I just tested this again in 2016 (version 1611 build 7571.2109 / 7095) and the AfterShapeSizeChange event is still not firing for me!

Comment: Same question two years on has been posted in EE here https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28999421/AfterShapeSizeChange-application-event-not-firing-in-PowerPoint.html#a41989047

Comment: Jamie, this event has been highly unreliable. I’ve seen it work at times. But the only time it triggers 100% of the time upon resize is with SmartArt and Charts. All other shape types have been hit or miss. It’s been reported to the dev team in the past.